# Trying to add markdown in my rails (version: 4.2.5) application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in ruby on rails it's also my first ruby application. Now I need to add markdown in my application I am following the below tutorial

http://crabonature.pl/posts/16-markdown-in-ruby-on-rails

But it's showing an error that is:

[image]

Also here is my codes details

View file code:

```
<%= form_for :postedJob, url: postANewJob_path(@postedJob), action: :create, method: :post, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }  do |f| %>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="title">Job Description</label>
            <%= markdown @upload_resumes.job_description %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Application_helper.rb code:

```
  require 'redcarpet'
  module ApplicationHelper
     def markdown(text)
       render_options = {
          filter_html: true,
          hard_wrap: true,
          link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow' }
       }

     renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(render_options)
     extensions = {
         autolink: true,
         fenced_code_blocks: true,
         lax_spacing: true,
         no_intra_emphasis: true,
         strikethrough: true,
         superscript: true
     }

     Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions).render(text).html_safe

    end
 end
```

Gem file code:

```
 gem 'redcarpet'
```

Someone can help me please where the bug

My rails version: 4.2.5

Comment: Have you done `bundle install`?  Is the `redcarpet` gem installed?

Comment: Yes I Installed bundle and redcarpet: 3.3.4

Comment: Please paste full error stack trace into the question. Linking pictures is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for good suggestion @MichalSzyndel

Comment: try adding `require 'redcarpert'` on top of your `application_helper.rb`

Comment: and it didn't help? can you try running Rails console and just type `Redcarpet` in there and see if the error happens as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100502/discussion-between-mukto-mona-and-michal-szyndel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try another one, not trying only markdown, you try `redactor`.

I think your solution the below link, here is very nicely representation:

- [redactor](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails)

Hope will find your solution

Answer (score 0):

From the `Rails.root` value I suppose you're running your application on windows. Some gems (and `redcarpet` is one of them) have native extension that must be compiled to make the gem work.

First, try to run `irb` right in your rails app folder. Then, try `require 'redcarpet'` in irb prompt. If this will give you an error, then extension did not compile properly.

You may fix this by installing `Ruby development kit`. It may be found here:
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
(look for DEVELOPMENT KIT and your windows architecture).

Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: At, first Thanks for answer. When I create application then installed Dev kit. Now after your answer also tried it's showing override.

Comment: What output did you get after running `irb` and `require "redcarpet"` there?

Comment: Good.
Then try those lines in `rails console`:

     `require 'redcarpet'; rr = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML);    rr.render("hello")`

And put output here.